# Using lapply to subset a list based on a condition to create a new list and keep the names of the elements

Tags: r, list, subset, lapply

I have a list of 20. Within the 20 lists is a list of around 200 shares ranked by market capitalization. There are 20 lists as the sort is done every six months from 2008 to 2018. I am sorting the shares into 5 portfolios of market capitalization. I have written code using lapply that extracts the 20th percentile of shares by market capitalisation and makes five different lists. The problem I have is that the new lists do not have element names. Since the each list is a list of lists with a list of 20 with each list having around 50 shares, I can't manually name them. I need a way to match the values in each list to the original list to get the names. The names of the shares is what I need; the names were originally rownames of a dataframe. Alternatively, is there a better method to lapply that keeps the names? I have provided an example with a list of 2, which has a nested list of 100 and illustrates the same problem I have.

```r
z <- as.double(1:100)
x <- as.double(200:299)
a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, 100, TRUE), FALSE))
b <- do.call(paste0, replicate(6, sample(LETTERS, 100, TRUE), FALSE))
z <- as.matrix(z)
x <- as.matrix(x)
rownames(z) <- a
rownames(x) <- b

mylist <- list(z, x)

portfolio_5 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x <= quantile(x, 0.2)])

portfolio_4 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x > quantile(x, 0.2) & x <= quantile(x, 0.4)])

portfolio_3 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x > quantile(x, 0.4) & x <= quantile(x, 0.6)])

portfolio_2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x > quantile(x, 0.6) & x <= quantile(x, 0.8)])

portfolio_1 <- lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x > quantile(x, 0.8) & x <= quantile(x, 1)])
```

The above code works but you will notice that the names of the elements in each list have been dropped. This is the same problem I have. How do I perform the above and still keep the name of each equity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is only a single column, we need `drop = FALSE` because the of the default property of `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
>
> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples)

The OP's `list` is a `list` of column matrices with row names When the `i` index is not provided, the `matrix` gets coerced to `vector` as it is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.  So, specify the logical index in `i`, leave the `j` as blank (to select all the columns) and then add the `drop = FALSE`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x <= quantile(x, 0.2),, drop = FALSE])
```